# PDO Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have three ":" (names)

```
$q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO '.PRFX.'u 
    (phone,mail,lvl,regdate,act_lnk,joined,name,first_time) 
    VALUE(:phone,:mail,0,"'.time().'","'.md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),1)).'","'.DATETIME.'",:name,1)');

$q->execute(
    array(
        'phone'=>$_POST['phone'],
        'mail'=>$_POST['mail'],
        'name'=>$_POST['name']
        )
    );
```

And they're matched. So why I get the error?

Comment: It is possible due to empty _POST['mail']? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Esacpe your string properly

Comment: I've did: `if(empty($_POST['mail'])) $_POST['mail'] = "0";` and it seemed to work

Comment: Is it possible to add EMPTY value to the db? and still take it without an error?

Comment: Thats will be based on your table structure like whether your table allows NULL values insertion

Comment: Added `if(empty($_POST['mail'])) $_POST['mail'] = "";` and works, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is guess  it should be

```
array(
        ':phone'=>$_POST['phone'],
        ':mail'=>$_POST['mail'],
        ':name'=>$_POST['name']
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix named parameters and real values inside the `prepare()` method like you do by using `0`, `time()` and other PHP functions.

The `prepare()` method needs to be free from real values because the DBMS don't expect any and won't parse the query. It only create an execution plan of the query. Your code should look like this:

```
$q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . PRFX . 'u 
    (phone,mail,lvl,regdate,act_lnk,joined,name,first_time) 
    VALUE(:phone,:mail,:lvl,:regDate,:actLink,:joined,:name,:firstTime)');

$q->execute(
    array(
        ':phone'    => $_POST['phone'],
        ':mail'     => $_POST['mail'],
        ':name'     => $_POST['name'],
        ':lvl'      => 0,
        ':regDate'  => time(),
        ':actLink'  => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),1)),
        'joined'    => DATETIME,
        'firstTime' => 1
        )
    );
```

You should also check if the `$_POST` variables you are going to use are set, not-empty and have the expected type of value.

Furthermore I recommend to use `bindValue()` for binding the values to the query. Then you can define also the variable type:

```
$q->bindValue(':phone', $_POST['phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindValue(':regDate', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
...
$q->execute();
```